# File load to Azure App Service root folder from another app service

Tags: .net, azure

I am trying to save file one of app service folder from another app service folder. 
Scenario:

I have admin app service hosted in Azure. Also I hosted my website which is different app service. Now I wish to save file from admin portal to website root like ~/content/...

How do I define the path in webconfig inside admin portal?

Best regards,
Shekhar

Comment: Thats a really un-good idea. If you need to share data between apps then use an API or a shared database.

Comment: I echo the sentiment of @Steveland83. This is not a good idea. I would also offer that Blob Storage is a quick\cheap way to achieve what you are trying to do as well.  Don't try to share local files in an app instances.

Comment: Hi Steve & Josh. Appreciate that you replied. I do agree that it is not the right way. I did it through fileserver or Azure blob storage in different project. Actually it is just a testing for dev environment which is in Azure. But Stage and Prod are in VM. Actually I try to use the same code of PROD without using API or modify anything. So I try to find out - is their any solution of this too tacle just for a testing? Thank you once again.